# How to control routing values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Maybe I don't understand real purpose of asp mvc routing.
I created an application and now I need to fix my url's a to be more understandable.
For example I have area `Cities` with controller `Home` and action `Index`.
So here I need url like: `localhost/London` but with current routing I get `localhost/cityPage/Home`.
My question is can I somehow pass parameter like `city name` and make URL like I want?
This is my  current default routing in Global.asax

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
                "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { area = "CityPage", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" },
                new string[] { "MyProject.Areas.Cities.Controllers" }).DataTokens.Add("area", "Cities");
```

New routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(null,
                            "CityPage/{cityName}",
                            new
                            {
                                area = "CityPage",
                                controller = "Home",
                                action = "Index"
                            }
                        );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
                "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { area = "CityPage", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" },
                new string[] { "MyProject.WebUI.Areas.CityPage.Controllers" }).DataTokens.Add("area", "CityPage");
```

Example of link that I click

```
@Html.ActionLink("City London", "Index", "Home", new { cityName = "London" }, null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to route the URL localhost/London to the Index action on the HomeController of the Cities area, you need a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(null,
    "{id}",
    new 
    {
        area = "Cities", controller = "Home", action = "Index"
    }
);
```

Be sure this route is declared before the "Default" route in your CitiesAreaRegistration.cs class.

However if you have a lot of other routes in your application, adding a general route like this can play havoc with other routes in the app. I suggest adding a URL prefix to separate this route from others in your application:

```
routes.MapRoute(null,
    "cities/{id}",
    new 
    {
        area = "Cities", controller = "Home", action = "Index"
    }
);
```

This will make your URL look like localhost/cities/London. Is that acceptable?

**Update 1**

Unless you completely remove your "Default" route definition, you will actually have multiple INBOUND routes that map to this action. You would have `localhost/cities/London`, `localhost/cityPage/Home`, `localhost/cityPage/Home/Index`, and `localhost/cityPage/Home/Index/London` all resolving to that action. However when MVC chooses to generate an OUTBOUND route, it will choose the first one -- localhost/cities/London.

**Update 2**

If you want your route parameter to be cityName, you would do this:

```
routes.MapRoute(null,
    "cities/{cityName}",
    new 
    {
        area = "Cities", controller = "Home", action = "Index"
    }
);
```

However you would then have to change the Index action on your Cities area's HomeController to have this signature:

```
public ActionResult Index(string cityName)
```

By changing the argument from id to cityName, you are telling MVC to pass this URL paramter / route segment to the action method.

**Update 3**

Is the name of your area "Cities" or "CityPage"? From previous code it looked like the name of your area was Cities.

If it is CitiesPage, try this for your action method:

```
@Html.ActionLink("City London", "Index", "Home", 
    new { area = "CityPage", cityName = "London" })
```

**Final Answer**

I just reproduced this in an MVC3 project, and it is working as expected:

1. Created a new area named "CityPage"
2. Added a HomeController with an Index action to the CityPage area
3. Added an Index view to the CityPage/Views/Home folder.

CityPageAreaRegistration.cs:

```
public class CityPageAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "CityPage";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(null,
            "CityPage/{cityName}",
            new { area = "CityPage", controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );

        //context.MapRoute(
        //    "CityPage_default",
        //    "CityPage/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        //    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        //);
    }
}
```

HomeController.cs:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /CityPage/Home/

    public ActionResult Index(string cityName)
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>
    Index</h2>
@Html.ActionLink("City London", "Index", "Home", 
    new { area = "CityPage", cityName = "London" }, null)
```

Finally, here is the link generated by the action link:

```
<a href="/CityPage/London">City London</a>
```

Comment: I added this before default but url is not changed :( How can I control {id} parameter?

Comment: Please add to your question how you want to control the {id} parameter.

Comment: I added my home/index action method code maybe I made there something wrong.

Comment: See my updates about changing the name of the route parameter and how it affects the method signature on your action method.

Comment: Ok now I see from where parameters come :) It's better but now url is http://localhost:34693/Cities/Home?cityName=London

Comment: Sounds like you need to read up on how routing works. For CityPage/London to work, your route has to be "CityPage/{cityName}". Are you using the routes in my answer, or changing them?

Comment: That was my mistake area is CityPage. However I tried to add area to action link but still same :(

Comment: Hmm... I have just created small demo project like you did and it is fine. I must deeper check project error must be somewhere else :(

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this way but you have to do following thing

1. Make sure your route must register before generic route.
2. Get Information about RouteConstraint

> http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs
>   http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs

Just for example Try this way check your required url localhost/London

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
                "{id}",
                new { area = "CityPage", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" },
                new string[] { "MyProject.Areas.Cities.Controllers" }).DataTokens.Add("area", "Cities");
```